# Assembly.ExecutingAssembly() GetType() doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Here is my code, it is very simple:

```
namespace EnumReflection
{
    enum Messengers
    {
      MSN,
      ICQ,
      YahooChat,
      GoogleTalk
    }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Messengers).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

      foreach (var field in fields)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
      }

      var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      var type = assembly.GetType("Messengers");

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

However, `type` variable is always null, even though when I say `assembly.GetTypes()`, it returns all types such as `Messengers`, `Program`.

Here is the copy of my Immediate Window:

```
assembly.GetType("Messengers");
null
assembly.GetTypes();
{System.Type[2]}
    [0]: {Name = "Messengers" FullName = "EnumReflection.Messengers"}
    [1]: {Name = "Program" FullName = "EnumReflection.Program"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Assembly.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) method is supposed to take the full name of the type, including namespace. Try passing `EnumReflection.Messengers` instead, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a full name in GetType() (i.e. uncluding namespace) in order to get a type